# How to combine multiple transforms for a 3D model?

Tags: rotation, translate

We are using Helix Toolkit to process 3D models. The scenario is that the object should be translated and rotated in a mixed order using Double up/down value input.

Multiple rotation on different axis works fine. However, when the object is translated on one of the axes, the following rotation moves the object instead of rotating with the existing offsets as it's center of rotation.

Here's the gist of steps-

1. Remove the existing MatrixTransform3D from the Transform3DGroup.
2. Create a new rotate or translate transform.
3. If the model is rotated, prepend the previous translate transform to the new  rotate transform.
4. If the model is translated, prepend the previous rotate transform to the new        translate transform.
5. Add the new matrixtransform3D to the transform3dgroup which is bound as the models transform in XAML.

I am wondering what is the right way to combine the translate and rotate transforms. Appreciate your help.

Code:

```
Matrix3D CalculateRotationMatrix()
{
    Point3D rotationCenter = new Point3D(-1 * MoveX.DataValue, -1 * MoveY.DataValue, -1 * MoveZ.DataValue);
    _rotateMatrix = new Matrix3D();

    _rotateMatrix.RotateAt(new Quaternion(_xAxisVector3D, RotateX.DataValue), rotationCenter);
    _rotateMatrix.RotateAt(new Quaternion(_yAxisVector3D * _rotateMatrix, RotateY.DataValue), rotationCenter);
    _rotateMatrix.RotateAt(new Quaternion(_zAxisVector3D * _rotateMatrix, RotateZ.DataValue), rotationCenter);

    return _rotateMatrix;
}

Matrix3D CalculateTranslationMatrix() {
    _translateMatrix = new Matrix3D();
    _translateMatrix.Translate(new Vector3D(MoveX.DataValue, MoveY.DataValue, MoveZ.DataValue));
    return _translateMatrix; }

void UpdateTransform(bool isRotate = false)
{
    if (ModelTransform.DataValue.Children.Count > 0)
    for (int i = 0; i < ModelTransform.DataValue.Children.Count; i++)
    {
    ModelTransform.DataValue.Children.Remove(ModelTransform.DataValue.Children[i]);
    }

    Matrix3D newMatrix3D;

    if (isRotate)
    {
        newMatrix3D = CalculateRotationMatrix();
        newMatrix3D.Append(_translateMatrix);
    }
    else
    {
        newMatrix3D = CalculateTranslationMatrix();
        newMatrix3D.Prepend(_rotateMatrix);
    }

    ModelTransform.DataValue.Children.Add(new MatrixTransform3D(newMatrix3D));
}
```

ModelTransform.DataValue is of type Transform3DGroup and is bound to the 3D model in xaml.

*Updated Code: (Rotate doesn't shift the model but not rotating around the new center point)*

```
void UpdateTransform(eMove move)
        {
            if (ModelTransform.DataValue.Children.Count > 0)
                for (int i = 0; i < ModelTransform.DataValue.Children.Count; i++)
                {
                    ModelTransform.DataValue.Children.Remove(ModelTransform.DataValue.Children[i]);
                }

            Matrix3D newMatrix3D = new Matrix3D();

            switch (move)
            {
                case eMove.Translate:
                    newMatrix3D = CalculateTranslationMatrix();
                    newMatrix3D.Prepend(_rotateMatrix);
                    break;
                case eMove.Rotate:
                    // Translate the model
                    newMatrix3D = _translateMatrix;
                    double xAfterRotateTranslate = newMatrix3D.OffsetX;
                    double yAfterRotateTranslate = newMatrix3D.OffsetY;
                    double zAfterRotateTranslate = newMatrix3D.OffsetZ;

                    // Rotate the model
                    newMatrix3D.Append(CalculateRotationMatrix());
                    _xAfterRotate = newMatrix3D.OffsetX;
                    _yAfterRotate = newMatrix3D.OffsetY;
                    _zAfterRotate = newMatrix3D.OffsetZ;

                    //Translate back the difference after the rotation
                    Matrix3D negativeTranslate = new Matrix3D();
                    negativeTranslate.Translate(new Vector3D(xAfterRotateTranslate - _xAfterRotate,
                    yAfterRotateTranslate - _yAfterRotate, zAfterRotateTranslate * _zAfterRotate));
                    newMatrix3D.Append(negativeTranslate);
                    break;
            }

            ModelTransform.DataValue.Children.Add(new MatrixTransform3D(newMatrix3D));
        }

Matrix3D CalculateTranslationMatrix()
        {
            _translateMatrix = new Matrix3D();
            _translateMatrix.Translate(new Vector3D(MoveX.DataValue, MoveY.DataValue, MoveZ.DataValue));
            return _translateMatrix;
        }

 Matrix3D CalculateRotationMatrix()
        {
            Point3D rotationCenter = new Point3D(-1 * MoveX.DataValue, -1 * MoveY.DataValue, -1 * MoveZ.DataValue);
            _rotateMatrix = new Matrix3D();

            _rotateMatrix.RotateAt(new Quaternion(_xAxisVector3D, RotateX.DataValue), rotationCenter);
            _rotateMatrix.RotateAt(new Quaternion(_yAxisVector3D * _rotateMatrix, RotateY.DataValue), rotationCenter);
            _rotateMatrix.RotateAt(new Quaternion(_zAxisVector3D * _rotateMatrix, RotateZ.DataValue), rotationCenter);

            return _rotateMatrix;
        }
```

Comment: Sounds like you are still rotating around the original center point pre-translation.  Would need to see your code and how the objects location is updated before being presented to the rotate method.

Comment: That's a good point. I tried rotating around the center of origin after the object has been translated, even so the final transform3dgroup's matrix3d object has offsets x,y,z not matching the actual translated values. I will edit the original post to add the code.

Comment: Apologies, looking at you 'updated code' and looking at the original question again I'm concerned that you are novice programmer, and that that is the problem here.   You have issues with variable scope and program logic.  I know that I often dive in at the deep end when tackling a new topic too, no shame. ... but I have to suggest that you do some basic programming tutorials and try again. Try writing a flowchart, paying attention to what variables are in scope.. good luck.

Comment: Sorry, if what you justified is true I don't believe that's the issue here. I have tried different ways to get the translation and rotation order in perspective but had no luck in achieving rotation around center point or a given point without the model shifting. And there are not much helpful info/examples from the search as to how to combine the translate and rotate. I'll go figure. Thanks for your time though!